# Correct column ordering in schema.rb when merging branches in Rails (git / db:migrate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, branching-and-merging, rails-migrations

In this question I'm particularly looking the at situation when:

- Merging feature branch into master
- Feature branch has a new migration eg: `123_add_foo.rb`
- Master branch has new migrations which are not in the feature branch eg: `456_add_bar.rb`

**Option 1**

When merging the `schema.rb` file, the result will be of the form

```
create_table "something", :force => true do |t|
  ...
  t.string   "foo" # foo was added to schema.rb earlier, so appears first
  t.string   "bar"
end
```

**Option 2**

However, running `rake db:migrate` will cause this to be reordered to look like

```
create_table "something", :force => true do |t|
  ...
  t.string   "bar" # bar was added to the master branch first
  t.string   "foo" # so this appears before foo here
end
```

**Question**

Which `schema.rb` should be stored in version control?

Option 2 matches what will happen when migrating the server - does it matter that this no longer matches what would happen when running the migrations from scratch?

Comment: I _think_ but have nothing to prove whatsoever, that you should scrap `schema.rb` coming from branch and run migrations after merging with master keeping generated schema.